# Area of subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definite-integrals, area

> Determine the area of $$ \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2 + y^2 \le r^2\}, (r \in (0, +\infty))$$

My problem is to get the correct definite integral. I think the limits are $0$ and $r$ because $r \in (0, \infty)$. Should I solve it with polar coordinates such that $$\int\limits_0^r cos^2(\phi)+sin^2(\phi) d\phi$$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It should be a double integral

Comment: This is a disk. Its area is $\pi r^2$

Comment: @AhmedHussein I'd assume that this is what he is supposed to show.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, it is.
So the limits are $\int\limits_0^{\infty}$?

Comment: To begin with, that region, as given, does NOT have an area.   For any fixed value of r it would be a circle with radius 0 without the center poinllt and so have area $\pi r^2$.  But for all r from 0 to infinity, it is the entire two dimensional plane except for one point.

Comment: @user247327 that sounds like nitpicking to me. It's rather clear that the OP wants to know, for given $r$, which is allowed to be in the range of the positive numbers, what the region of the set of $x, y$ with $x^2+y^2 \le r$ is. The curly braces indicating the set in question do not include the statement from where $r$ has to be taken, so the formulation is, as far as I'm concerned, precise enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a solution without double integral you may divide the set in the parts where $y>0$ and $y<0$ and calculate
$$\int_{-r}^r \sqrt{r^2-x^2}\, dx$$
which is the area between the $x$- axis and the upper part of the circle. The total area is then twice this value. (In other words you solve for $y$, and get two solutions which, together, make up the circle).

(the integral in question should be Bronstein integrable).

Answer (score 0):

Its $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^r tdtd\theta $, and this is the area of the disk radius $r$.

Comment: Is there a way without a double integral?

Comment: @jacmeird:  The double integral simplifies, since dummy variable $t$ and its limits do not depend on $\theta$.  Therefore integral with respect to $\theta$ "factors out" and gives us $2\pi$ as a constant multiplier on the single integral.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the radius $R$ instead of $r$. In polar coordinates, we have that $\phi$ varies from $0$ to $2\pi$ (it makes a complete turn), and $r$ varies from $0$ to $R$ (just draw the region to see it). The area is then just:

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^R r dr d\phi = \pi R^2$$

because the original integral is:

$$\iint_A dx dy$$

(Where $A$ is the region you described)

and the Jacobian of the transformation $(r, \phi) \mapsto (r \cos \phi, r \sin \phi)$ is $r$.